# Rejecting requests with expired/invalid client certificate on enginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, client-certificates

We have a nginx server running with client certificate verification on. By default nginx sends 400 for requests with expired client certificate . Our motive is to drop/reject that request at nginx without sending any response to client. How can we override nginx default behaviour, code below didn't work in server block

```
if ($ssl_client_verify = "FAILED") {
   return 444;
}
```

Comment: I know this is super old, but came across this same issue during test. What version of nginx are you running, and are you sure that's the error message? When I supply expired certificates, I get: `FAILED:certificate has expired`, so your condition might not be firing. Separately, I _think_ you always need to send some sort of response to the user, or they'll implicitly get a `timeout`?